# How to open webpage from wireframesketcher link?

Tags: application-development

I have a WireFrameSketcher screen, in which I want to be able to click the link and open the web page.

I haven't been able to do that. I'm also not sore if that is possible. If anyone knows a way to do it, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for external links was added in [WireframeSketcher v3.8.1](http://wireframesketcher.com/blog/2013-01-07-external-links-vertical-tabs-better-html-viewer.html).